# Makefile sample codes in Windows 7 SDK

Tags: windows, authentication, makefile

I want to write custom SSP/AP (Security Support Provider / Authentication package) for Windows 7, so according to MSDN I should download Windows 7 SDK sample codes and start from them. I did it and I found there only folders with makefiles (...samples/security/authentication), not Visual Studio solutions.

I tried to execute "nmake Makefile" on Developer Command Prompt for VS2015, but it seems not to support makefiles written for NT platform.

Does anybody have any idea how to run this makefiles and generate .dll?

Or does anybody have some sample codes for writing my custom SSP/AP?

Comment: Is there an error message reported by `nmake` ?

Comment: In makefile is this statemant: 
!IF "$(TARGETOS)" == "WINNT"
and it does not pass it. If I delete that line then it cannot pass next line: 
!include <win32.mak>
I am confused with NT platform makefile shiped with windows 7 SDK.

Comment: Message is: makefile(9) : fatal error U1052: file "win32.mak" not found

Comment: Why is tagged with C++ AND C?

Comment: Although it is c++ project with this metafile, they are not essential tags and I will remove them. Thanks for suggestion.